# Storing two mouse events on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm currently using matplotlib and I need to store coordinates of two left clicks on a graph. (I'm calculating an integral between the two clicked points) Somehow, after hours and hours of trying, I haven't managed to save the two clicks.  Does anybody here know how to do that?

Comment: This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ginput()` function.  Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data to plot
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)

print('please click twice on the plot')

clicks = []
for i in range(2):
    clicks.append(plt.ginput())

print('your clicks were at locations:')
print(clicks)
```